# Is it possible to recover classes source code from Maven jar?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, recover

Is it possible to recover source code of java classes (not all), after build in Maven??
I have got compiled jar, but I deleted two classes of my code..

Thx for helping.

Comment: Try JD-Gui java decompiler.

Comment: Use java decompiler [http://jd.benow.ca]

Comment: Did you install your code to a maven repository? Then there is a good chance you also uploaded a sources.jar for that artificat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible with [java decompiler](https://www.google.pl/search?q=java+decompiler&oq=java+decompiler) only. [Maven Source Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/) is not enabled by default in normal maven build.

Most modern Java IDE has internal project versioning builtin, maybe you can recover deleted file from IDE. For example IDEA IntelliJ has option [Show Local History](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/local_history.html).

Comment: +1 for advising to use the `show local history` option. Can't tell you how many times it has saved me !